# default_gain.conf not present (for volume)

Tags: volume

I have been editing my default_gain.conf on my android devices for as ong as I can remember now.

I recently upgraded to the Note 4 (***N9100F***) and I cant seem to find this file anywhere. My device is rooted BTW.

The location should be **/system/etc/default_gain.conf** but it isn't there.

I also have a Samsung Galaxy Nexus running CM11 that I have disabled the radio and deleted all of the bloatware on, just so it can be used as a media player and I can't find the file on that device either.

Has the location been changed and I haven't noticed or do I now need to edit some other file to up the volume of my music player without using third-party apps?

I appreciate the help guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the app [speaker booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wait.what.volume.booster) on the play store. It claims to increase your volume/loudness by (up to) 30%, and I must say that (after trying it) it's pretty successful, with a handful of devices not getting boosted by it (it made my LG G2 quieter)

Also, it does not need root.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try it out. The problem with apps is that they like to mess with the EQ, which in effect messes with the quality, is this something you have noticed?

Comment: Not really. Then again, my speakers tank everything. Also, I have never noticed this mess with my EQ, but it does toggle Xloud (Sony thing) when I turn the booster off (after boosted, exit, relaunch, turn all volume to 0 in-app and exit to turn booster off)